# Is it safe to assume that the animationend event is always fired in document order?

Tags: javascript, css-animations, dom-events

Consider the following example.

```js
const g = document.querySelector("g");

g.addEventListener("animationend", event => {
  console.log("animationend", event.target.id);
});

const circles = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("circle")).reverse();

const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const main = async () => {
  await sleep(2000);
  for (const circle of circles) circle.classList.remove("hidden");
  await sleep(2000);
  for (const circle of circles) circle.classList.add("hidden");
  await sleep(2000);
  for (const circle of circles) circle.classList.remove("hidden");
  await sleep(2000);
  for (const circle of circles) circle.classList.add("hidden");
  await sleep(2000);
  for (const circle of circles) circle.classList.remove("hidden");
};

main();
```

```css
@keyframes moveEast {
  from { transform: translateX(0); }
  to { transform: translateX(80px); }
}

@keyframes moveWest {
  from { transform: translateX(0); }
  to { transform: translateX(-80px); }
}

#circle1 {
  animation: moveEast 333.33ms linear forwards;
}

#circle2 {
  animation: moveWest 333.33ms linear forwards;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<svg width="160" height="160">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#0A0A0A" />
  <g stroke="#0A0A0A" stroke-width="1" fill="#B22222">
    <circle id="circle1" class="hidden" r="10" cx="40" cy="40" />
    <circle id="circle2" class="hidden" r="10" cx="120" cy="120" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

In Chrome, every time the animation is restarted the `animationend` event is fired for `circle1` before `circle2`. This is despite the fact that we remove the `hidden` class from `circle2` before `circle1`. So, is it safe to assume that the `animationend` event is always fired in document order? This is for animations which begin and end at the same time.

The reason I want to know this is because I want to do something, but only after all the animations are over. Hence, I want to attach the `animationend` event listener to only the last element. If there's a better way to solve this problem then I'm all ears.

Comment: In this exact case both animations are actually started at the same painting frame, so yes, DOM order *should* win. But are you really in this case? Why can't you just wait for all events to fire? Is it actually safe in your setup to even wait for these events? Are you 100% sure that nothing can prevent these animations to perform 'til the end? IMM the safest is is to keep it simple and use good'ol timeouts here.